# Prove $\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{3}\ge2\left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}}+\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{a+b+c}\right)$

Tags: inequality, quadratics, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

> Problem: Let $a,b,c,d>0.$ Prove that: $$\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt{3}\ge2\left(\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}}+\frac{\sqrt{ab+bc+ca}}{a+b+c}\right)$$
> It is my old teacher's problem.

My attempt: I guess a=b=c=d so using C-S inequality: $$R.H.S\le2\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}+\frac{ab+bc+ca}{(a+b+c)^2}}$$
But it seems weak to get the proof. I hope we can find a good solution for nice problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe consider the inequalities involving the harmonic, geometric and arithmetic means

Comment: *Small hint*: WLOG $d=3$.

Comment: Thank you. I think we can assume that sum=1 due to homogeneity, but the rest is quite complicated

Comment: @user10354138. Can you tell me why

Comment: Note that rescaling $(a,b,c,d)\mapsto(\lambda a,\lambda b,\lambda c,\lambda d)$ does not change either side.  So if you pick $d=3$ and rearrange ...

Comment: Oh, i see. Very useful hint! And then we also wlog a+b+c=3, and work for 1 variable function

Answer (score 2):

We need to prove that:
$$\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt3-\frac{2\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}{a+b+c}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{d}{a+b+c}}$$ and since $$\sqrt3(a+b+c)\geq2\sqrt{ab+ac+bc},$$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\frac{d}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}+\sqrt3-\frac{2\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}{a+b+c}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{d\left(\sqrt3-\frac{2\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}{a+b+c}\right)}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}}.$$
Thus, it's enough to prove that:
$$\frac{\sqrt3-\frac{2\sqrt{ab+ac+bc}}{a+b+c}}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}}\geq\frac{1}{a+b+c}.$$
Now, let $a^2+b^2+c^2=t(ab+ac+bc).$

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\frac{\sqrt3-\frac{2}{\sqrt{t+2}}}{\sqrt{t}}\geq\frac{1}{\sqrt{t+2}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{3(t+2)}\geq2+\sqrt{t},$$ which is true by C-S:
$$\sqrt{3(t+2)}=\sqrt{(2+1)(2+t)}\geq2+\sqrt{t}.$$

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. I think we also use directly AM-GM

Comment: @3017 You are welcome!

Comment: $a^2+b^2+c^2=(a+b+c+\sqrt{2ab+2ac+2bc})(a+b+c-\sqrt{2ab+2ac+2bc})$